# In VSCode integrated Terminal, how to pass mouse event?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

As title.

For more environment details, I am using the default configure in VSCode. I connected to my server via SSH in the VSCode integrated terminal. I can use VIM to edit files. I have configured for VIM to enable mouse click in `.vimrc` as below.

```
" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

It works fine when I use other terminals. Does anyone know what I should configure in VSCode or `.vimrc`?